# Dynamically split 3 divs

Tags: html, dynamic, split

I need to have three divs to dynamically split the space of a container depending on their display property. If all three are displayed, then the user should see three equally split divs (1/3, 1/3, 1/3). If only two are displayed then user should see 1/2 and 1/2. And if only one is visible then it should fill all container space.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>equal div</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        #container{width: 100%, height: 100%;background: #666;}
        #container div{ float: left; border: 1px solid #000; margin: -1px; background: red}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
        var c = $('#container').children('div').length;
        $('#container').children().css('width', 100/c+'%');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.